# $f(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, If $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=a$,then show $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x+1) - f(x))=a$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Prove that if $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and
$\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=a$

then,

show $\lim_{x \to \infty}\big(f(x+1) - f(x))=a$

I think I use the mean-value theorem. But I can't solve it.

Comment: Yes the mean value theorem is the way to go. Apply it and use the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the limiting value and the error term and guess what looks like the original function $f$.

In your case, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x) = a$ means

$$f'(x)=a + h(x)~~ \textrm{where}~~h(x)\rightarrow0~~\textrm{as}~~x\rightarrow \infty.$$

Then the original function $f$ will have the form:
$$f(x)=ax + \tilde{h}(x).$$

Your estimate will be
$$|f(x+1) - f(x) -a|\rightarrow0~~\textrm{as}~~{x\rightarrow\infty}.$$

Maybe you need to make these steps rigorous by using the Mean value Theorem as you noticed.